# is there a package which validate Elasticsearch query params?

Tags: rest, validation, elasticsearch

I want to create Elasticsearch query by myself and I looking for a package which will validate the query parameters (By the query type).

for example:

```
GET /_search?analyze_wildcard=true { //RANDOM BOD }  - I'll get true
```

and for:

```
GET /_search?INVALID_PARAMETER=true { //RANDOM BOD }  - I'll get false
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you, let me know if you have more updated information, I am more than happy to add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question, but As far as I remember there is no such package available but you can build one for yourself and it wouldn't be difficult to build one as you most probably don't need to validate all the query types.